# как вывести данные вместо id связанных таблиц WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных, sqlite, entity-framework

есть таблицы связанные между собой в БД (SQLite), также классы

```
    public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    public int? OfficeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Office Office { get; set; }

    private string email;
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { email = value; OnPropertyChanged("Email"); }
    }
    private string password;

    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set { password = value; OnPropertyChanged("Password"); }
    }


    private string lastname;

    public string Lastname
    {
        get { return lastname; }
        set { lastname = value; OnPropertyChanged("Lastname"); }
    }

    private string birthdate;

    public string Birthdate
    {
        get { return birthdate; }
        set { birthdate = value; OnPropertyChanged("Birthdate"); }
    }

    private string active;

    public string Active
    {
        get { return active; }
        set { active = value; OnPropertyChanged("Active"); }
    }

    private string firstname;

    public string Firstname
    {
        get { return firstname; }
        set { firstname = value; OnPropertyChanged("Firstname"); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}

    public class Role : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private string title;
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public Role()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set 
        { 
            title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}


    public class Office : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? CountrieId { get; set; }
    public Countrie Countrie { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public Office()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
    private string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; OnPropertyChanged("Title"); }
    }
    private string phone;

    public string Phone
    {
        get { return phone; }
        set { phone = value; OnPropertyChanged("Phone"); }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}

     public class Countrie : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Office> Offices { get; set; }

    public Countrie()
    {
        Offices = new List<Office>();
    }
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

и контекст

```
using System.Data.Entity;

    namespace Session1
    {
    public class ContextDB : DbContext
    {
        public ContextDB() : base("MyConn") { }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Office> Offices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Countrie> Countries { get; set; }
    }
    }
```

и еще xaml  код

```
             <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="auto">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Firstname}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last name" Binding="{Binding Lastname}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Birthdate}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="User role" Binding="{Binding RoleId}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email address" Binding="{Binding Email}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Office" Binding="{Binding OfficeId}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

код к нему

```
     ContextDB db;
     public AdminPanel()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        db = new ContextDB();
        db.Users.Load();
        DataContext = db.Users.Local.ToBindingList();
     }
```

при запуске выводятся
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
как сделать так, чтобы вместо id в столбцах User role и office выводились данные
например так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то ваши скриншоты не совпадают с моделью, которую вы показали в коде, например отсутствует `Firstname`. Следовательно, угадать как оно правильно должно быть, у меня не получилось. Но в целом [вот так это делается](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21051612/12888024).

Comment: я их через INotifyPropertyChanged сделал кусочек кода 
 `private string firstname;

        public string Firstname
        {
            get { return firstname; }
            set { firstname = value; OnPropertyChanged("Firstname"); }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }`

Comment: Кусочки кода надо добавлять прямо в пост, его можно редактировать. Код в комментариях нечитабелен.

Comment: @aepot, хорошо, извиняюсь, код может причинить боль глазам, если есть элементарные ошибки или лучший способ, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Например свойство Role можно модифицировать так `public Role Role => db.Roles.First(r => r.Id == RoleId);` В таблице привязаться к нему, а не к `RoleId`. Ну или способ, что я выше указал с джойнами тоже подойдет. В сеттере свойства можно писать Id обпратно в RoleId. С офисами тоже самое.

Comment: `Countrie` - это страна? Если да, то это слово по-другому пишется `Country`.

Comment: @aepot, хорошо, спасибо большое

Comment: @aepot, по поводу страны, да, в курсе, но в документации так и написано, не стал перечить))